# Are modular representations isomorphic if they're isomorphic after raising to the pth power?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Consider algebraic representations of a reductive group $G$ over a field in characteristic $p$. I even want to allow *potentially disconnected* reductive groups, i.e. $G$ could be a finite group. (However I'm also interested if the behavior in the connected case is different.)

If $V$ and $W$ are two such representations with $V^{\otimes p}$ ismomorphic to $W^{\otimes p}$, are $V$ and $W$ necessarily isomorphic?

In characteristic $\neq p$ this is obviously false because you can tensor with a character of order $p$, but my question is in characteristic $p$.

Comment: Over some rings, there are (non-finitely generated) modules $M \neq 0$ so that $M \otimes M = 0$. Can this happen in this situation?

Comment: Here the tensor products are over the field $k$, so no: for this question we would never be worried about something like that. Also, when I said "algebraic representation" I meant finite-dimensional.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course you're tensoring over $k$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's one way of constructing counterexamples for finite groups.

Suppose $M$ is a periodic $kG$-module with period $p$: i.e., the $p$th syzygy $\Omega^pM$ is isomorphic to $M$, but $\Omega M\not\cong M$. Then
$$(\Omega M)^{\otimes p}\cong \Omega^pM\otimes M^{\otimes (p-1)}\cong M^{\otimes p},$$
up to projective direct summands.

If $G$ is a $p$-group, so that all projective $kG$-modules are free, then taking the direct sum of $|G|$ copies of $M$ and of $\Omega M$, and adding a free direct summand to whichever is smaller, we can get two modules $X$ and $Y$ of the same dimension, and then $X^{\otimes p}\cong Y^{\otimes p}$ (since they're isomorphic up to free direct summands and have the same dimension).

For example, take $p=2$ and $G$ the quaternion group $Q_8$. The trivial module $k$ has period $4$, so $M=k\oplus\Omega^2k$ has period $2$. $M$ has dimension $10$ and $\Omega M$ has dimension $14$, so in this case we can take the direct sum of two copies of each module (rather than $|G|=8$ copies), to get modules $X=k\oplus k\oplus\Omega^2k\oplus\Omega^2k\oplus kG$ and $Y=\Omega k\oplus\Omega k\oplus \Omega^3k\oplus\Omega^3k$ with $X^{\otimes 2}\cong Y^{\otimes 2}$.

Examples of suitable periodic modules for odd $p$ can be found in

*Carlson, Jon F.*, [**Periodic modules with large periods**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2042990), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 76, 209-215 (1979). [ZBL0419.20011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0419.20011).

Comment: On the other hand, I think that $X$ and $Y$ must have the same Brauer character if $X^{\otimes p} = Y^{\otimes p}$ so that they are isomorphic if one adds additional assumptions such as simplicity.

Comment: Very helpful! Now I wonder about the situation for connected reductive groups...

Comment: @user125639 You should probably accept this answer and ask a separate question for the connected case (with a link to this question).